# superset cannot query the kylin's data?

Tags: apache-superset

I link to kylin datasource and kylin's data can preview in sqllab,when enter the sql in sqllab,click the `run query` button,query status always pending and http reponse like

```
{"query": {"changedOn": 1574996199515.888, "changed_on": "2019-11-29T02:56:39.515888", "dbId": 4, "db": "Kylin", "endDttm": null, "errorMessage": null, "executedSql": null, "id": "5H-DGzWuw", "limit": 1000, "progress": 0, "rows": null, "schema": "DEFAULT", "ctas": false, "serverId": 59, "sql": "select a.country,a.name from DEFAULT.KYLIN_COUNTRY ", "sqlEditorId": "k7GQtMhzk", "startDttm": 1574996199504.259033, "state": "pending", "tab": "Untitled Query", "tempTable": "", "userId": 1, "user": "admin user", "resultsKey": null, "trackingUrl": null, "extra": {}}}
```

how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resovled,the datasource choosed asynchronous query.